# ./bin/istioctl context-create segmentation fault

Tags: istio

I'm following this guide of installing istio https://istio.io/docs/setup/consul/quick-start.html

At step 7, I noticed that pilot terminates after I run  docker-compose -f install/consul/istio.yaml up -d

So I ran istioctl context-create.
And I got a seg fault:

`./bin/istioctl context-create
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x1debb79]`

`goroutine 1 [running]:
main.getDefaultNamespace(0xc42021c620, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0)`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/cmd/istioctl/main.go:700 +0x99
main.glob..func4(0x2892960, 0x28be4b8, 0x0, 0x0)`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/cmd/istioctl/main.go:86 +0x39
istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x2892960, 0x28be4b8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2892960, 0x28be4b8)`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:637 +0x549
istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x2891760, 0x1df15f3, 0x0, 0x0)`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:729 +0x339
istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x2891760, 0x0, 0x154)`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:688 +0x2b
main.main()`
    `/home/sebastienvas/go/src/istio.io/pilot/cmd/istioctl/main.go:531 +0xc0`

I upgraded to the latest go version:
go version
go version go1.9.2 darwin/amd64
And still the same issue

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there could be a few problems in your setup, but it's going to take some follow-up questions to narrow it down.  This would be better suited as a question in the istio-users google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/istio-users where the problem can get diagnosed through some back-and-forth.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to the problem appear in the release of 0.3.1. Meanwhile, you can just copy https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/install/consul/kubeconfig into your install/consul directory.